# How can I add Jenkins-Slave node dynamically when running Jenkins Build?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-agent

I want to create a parameterized pipeline build which have an input of IP/Hostname. When I run the Jenkins Build, It should connect to the IP/Hostname and configure the machine as Jenkins-Slave. And the next job should run on the Slave machine.

Is there any plugin available to achieve this task?